# Windows.Web.Http Authentication with a blank username / only password

Tags: c#

I'm new to developing Windows 10 Universal Apps. I need to authenticate with `Windows.Web.Http` with a blank/empty username and only with a password. If I use a empty string or null I've got an exception on creating the credentials.

Any idea?

Comment: It's always a good idea to include the exception type and message when you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've got it by myself:

First I tried using (empty username throws Invalid Argument exception):

```
filter.ServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(uri.ToString(), username, pass);
```

Now I am using:

```
var buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(username + ":" + pass, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
```